# In DataStage, how do you extract an element together with a list of elements from an XML file

Tags: datastage

so I've spent hours trying to figure this out. I'm basically trying to read an xml document (using the Hierarchical Data stage). Then I need to output the contents of that document into a dataset with two columns.

The difficulty is that in the xml document I read from an element and then I need to read from a list of elements; Specifically productID and SubjectCode.

[image: Content of XML file to read]

The output I need is this

[image: Output I'd like to get]

But I'm getting the following error because DataStage doesn't want to associate a single element  with a multiple list element .

[image: Error from DataStage]

I should mention that if subjectCode was a single element like productID, it works fine. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies, I'm not at a computer to deliver screenshots but I recall having a similar issue and this answer is intended to give you some more options to try (if you haven't already done these!)

I believe you can set `subjectCode` as the "top" element and then the mapping for `productID` would become `../productID`

Failing that, you can right click and set `subjectCode` element differently  within the `XML_Parser`_step in order to create a repeater element there

I believe the Datastage XML Integration Redbook covers off the above and is available from the IBM for free